# Office 365 Administration - PowerShell

Tags: system, office365, powershell-3.0

Is there a way to export a list of all 365 users displaying if they are hidden from the GAL or not?  I looked online and wasn't able to find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Did the `get-msoluser` work for you?

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you for your help!